# No matching constructor for initialisation of class

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, initialization, ncurses

Cant see what i'm doing wrong ...

my GameWindow.h has code -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace::std;
class GameWindow{
    string WindowType;
    string WindowName;
    int TopLeftX,TopLeftY;
    int Height,Width;
    bool GetBoxed;
public:
    GameWindow(string WinType, string WinName,int TLX,int TLY,int y,int x,bool box);
    void SetHeight(int y);
    void SetWidth(int x);
    void SetTopLeftY(int TLY);
    void SetTopLeftX(int TLY);
};
```

And the source file code being -

```
#include "GameWindow.h"

GameWindow::GameWindow(string WinType, string WinName,int TLX,int TLY,int y,int x,bool box){
    WindowType = WinType; WindowName = WinName;
    TopLeftX = TLX; TopLeftY = TLY;
    Height = y; Width = x;
    GetBoxed = box;
};

void GameWindow::SetHeight(int y){Height = y;}
void GameWindow::SetWidth(int x){Width = x;}
void GameWindow::SetTopLeftY(int TLY){TopLeftY=TLY;}
void GameWindow::SetTopLeftX(int TLX){TopLeftX=TLX;}
```

so then in another source file i attempt to create a vector of GameSpace and call the constructor each time i add one to the vector -

```
int OffsetX =5;

    vector<GameWindow>GameSpace;

    GameSpace.resize(8);
    GameSpace[0] = GameWindow("MonstersLeftWin", "Misc", 
    (getmaxx(stdscr)-22-OffsetX), 2, 1, 22, true);
```

i get the "no matching constructor for initialisation of GameWindow" error. Cant see what im doing wrong at all!

i also get the error if i have -

```
    GameSpace[0] = *new GameWindow("MonstersLeftWin", "Misc", 
    (getmaxx(stdscr)-22-OffsetX), 2, 1, 22, true);
```

still unsure if i need the "new" there or not.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `using namespace` in a header file is a bad idea, and `*new Foo()` btw too, also you should use member initialization lists instead of assigning each varaible in the constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the `GameSpace.resize(8)` statement. As soon as you provide a custom constructor, the compiler wont generate a default constructor for you anymore. However, `std::vector` will default initialize elements in the resize call.

Either provide a default constructor (preferred): `GameWindow()`

Or use the `void resize (size_type n, const value_type& val);` overload

Answer (score 1):

In this statement

```
GameSpace.resize(8);
```

the compiler tries to call the default constructor of class GameWindow. However the class has no default constructor. So the compiler issues the error.

Instead of

```
GameSpace.resize(8);
```

you could write for example something as

```
GameSpace.resize( 8, { "", "", 0, 0, 0, 0, false }  );
```